# add "current" class to the current element of a navigation bar removing this class from the previous item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add a `current` class on the active item removing it from the previous item. It works but the pages don't change when I click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#navbarSupportedContent li a').click(function() {
      $('#navbarSupportedContent li').removeClass('current');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li.current a { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse clearfix" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navigation clearfix menuItems">
    <li class="current"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">A propos</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Nos services</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `return false;` will cancel the navigation.   Your next question will be, but when the page navigates it removes the `current` class.   Reminder that javascript only works on the *current* page.  When you navigate to a different page, you're on a different page and need to handle the `<li class="current"` on the page that you're on, you can't rely on javascript from the previous page.

Comment: This comes up 3-4 times a week (anecdotal) - I believe @RoryMcCrossan provided a complete answer to one of these relatively recently

Comment: You are right. But how can i the <li class="current" on the page that i am on ?

Comment: Easiest depends on how you build your .navigation.menuItems - if it's coded in each page then, really simply, edit your about.html/about.php(etc) and change `class="current"` so that it's on the about `li` / repeat for other pages.  If it's an include, then pass in a parameter in your model.   Harder options include parsing the url, but numerous questions on SO indicate people find this a bit harder.  Or using sessionStorage to store which page is being navigated to.

Comment: it was so easy !!! Thank you.